# how to subset a data frame based on specific or similar strings

Tags: r

As an example, I created a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Names = c("AA", "ab", "CC", "AVY"), Column1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), Column2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Column3 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I want to subset and keep those rows that have my strings in them lets say 3 of them
if I want to find the position, I can using the following to find where CC is

```
which(df=="CC", arr.ind=TRUE)
```

or if I want to find two of them CC and ab , I can

```
which(df==c("CC","ab"), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

but what I want is to subset it in a new data frame like below

```
Name    Column1 Column2 Column3
ab       0       0       0
CC       0       0       0
```

I found for one string at the time based on other people solutions but still if I have more than one I dont know how to do it

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) grepl("CC",x)),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` or `subset`, no need for `which` or `sapply`.

```
df[df$Names %in% c("CC","ab"), ]
#   Names Column1 Column2 Column3
# 2    ab       0       0       0
# 3    CC       0       0       0

subset(df, Names %in% c("CC","ab"))
#   Names Column1 Column2 Column3
# 2    ab       0       0       0
# 3    CC       0       0       0
```

`%in%` is a close relative of `match`.

```
df$Names %in% c("CC","ab")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

basically does

```
!is.na(match(df$Names, c("CC","ab")))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: do you know how to find it when it is in column name without converting to row ?

Comment: Try adding _two_ commas and `drop=FALSE`, `df[df$Names %in% c("CC","ab"), ,drop=FALSE]`, should prevent from coercing to a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this kind of solution:

With `str_detect` we could define the strings to filter in a pattern with the `|` (or) operator:

```
library(dplyr)
libray(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Names, 'CC|ab'))
```

```
  Names Column1 Column2 Column3
1    ab       0       0       0
2    CC       0       0       0
```

Comment: is it case sensitive? for instance if it is cc will it also bring it? if yes I Love it , I liked it already

Comment: Not case sensicitve. But no problem. Either add to pattern : 'CC|ab|cc' or use prior `tolower()` function etc...

Comment: I mean the pattern `'CC|ab'` is not case sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

or if you know the names you want ahead of time...

```
library(dplyr)

my_names=c("ab","CC")

df_subset<-df %>%
  filter(Names %in% my_names)
```

Comment: is it case sensitive ? for instance if it is cc does it still bring it? I liked it already

Comment: No, filter would require an exact match. If you need case insensitive, you can use (?i)  with str_detect      df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Names, '(?i)cc|ab'))